# How can a former citizen get a proof of name change for a chinese visa application?

Tags: visas, paperwork, us-citizens, china, applications

I'm a former chinese citizen who has became an US Citizen. I want to apply for a visa to go visit China again but I went through a name change during the naturalization process for my US citizenship. The chinese embassy is asking for a proof of name change from a court who approved this and I don't have this. I just found this out and have 3 weeks to my flights departure.

Has anyone been through this process and know how to work around this quickly?

I tried to get this document from UCSIS but apparently the process is lenghtly.

Comment: A more descriptive title for your question is prefered here at Travel.SE which makes it easier to understand what the question is about. 

Comment: Did you get your name change through a USCIS judge at your naturalization ceremony, or via a state court judge?

Comment: Putting on hold until OP returns to clarify.